# Unit testing a AWS Spring Boot Configuration file - possible?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

We are currently using Spring Boot to connect to a mocked local instance of Amazon SQS. The application itself is working when run, but we would like to try and test the SQS Config class, if possible and if it makes sense.

Here is the configuration class. All properties are pulled from the typical `application.properties` file when the Spring application itself is run.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AWSSQSConfig {
    @Value("${aws.sqs.endpoint}")
    private String AWSSqsEndpoint;

    // Producer QueueMessageTemplate
    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs, ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver) {
        if (!AWSSqsEndpoint.isEmpty())
            amazonSqs.setEndpoint(AWSSqsEndpoint);

        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver);
    }
}
```

Here is the test class. We are attempting to pass the configuration in via TestPropertySource, but they don't actually seem to get to the `AWSSQSConfig` class. `AWSSqsEndpoint` inside the instance of the class is always NULL.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.lonewolf.formsbuilder.config.AWSSQSConfig;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1",
        "cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=zzzzz",
        "cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=zzzzzz",

        "aws.sqs.endpoint = http://localhost:9324",
        "aws.sqs.requestQueue = CreateSchemaRequest",
        "aws.sqs.responseQueue = CreateSchemaResponse"
})
public class AWSSQSConfigTests {
    @Mock
    private AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs;

    @Mock
    private ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        AWSSQSConfig config = new AWSSQSConfig();

        QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate = config.queueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver);

        assertNotNull("The response body must not be null", queueMessagingTemplate);
    }
}
```

Is this a chicken and the egg situation, where the spring framework actually needs to run first to inject those config values? Do we need an integration test here instead?

**EDIT with working solution...**

Using the accepted answer, here is my working test! I was able to remove my dependency of the Spring framework.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AWSSQSConfigTests {
    @Mock
    private AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs;

    @Mock
    private ResourceIdResolver resourceIdResolver;

    @InjectMocks
    private AWSSQSConfig config;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(config, "AWSSqsEndpoint", "http://fake");
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate = config.queueMessagingTemplate(amazonSqs, resourceIdResolver);

        assertNotNull("The response body must not be null", queueMessagingTemplate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried injecting mock to your class (or autowire it), and then setting that field it using ReflectionTestUtils? This is a nice test utils class that Spring provides that allows you to do something like what you want without doing code modifications. 
I mean something like this:

```
    @InjectMocks
    private AWSSQSConfig awssqsConfig;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(awssqsConfig, "AWSSqsEndpoint", "putYourEndpointHere");
    }
```

Comment: I was so hung up on trying to leverage the framework's auto configuration - I didn't even think of using Reflection injection. That worked great - thanks! I've added the working test class to my question.